# How to add a delete button in javascript table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a little problem with this table. When there are data inside the table , the button delete does'nt appear. For that, I must add a new row.

How to appear this element in all the row inside the table because it's impossible the delete a row if there are data inside. That's my problem.

Thank you

```
     <table  id="myTableAttributesOptions" class="table table-sm table-hover order-list-bot">
            <thead>
              <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
                <td><?php echo $OSCOM_ProductsAttributesNew->getDef('text_heading_attributes_option_value_name'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $OSCOM_ProductsAttributesNew->getDef('text_heading_attributes_image'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $OSCOM_ProductsAttributesNew->getDef('text_heading_attributes_sort_order'); ?></td>
                <td class="text-md-right"><?php echo $OSCOM_ProductsAttributesNew->getDef('text_heading_attributes_actions'); ?></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
  $i = 0;
  while ($QoptionsValue->fetch()) {
?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo HTML::inputField('name[' . $i . ']', $QoptionsValue->value('name'), 'id="name[' . $i . ']"'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo HTML::inputField('image[' . $i . ']', $QoptionsValue->value('image'), 'id="image[' . $i . ']"'); ?></td>
                <td class="text-md-right"><?php echo HTML::inputField('sort_order[' . $i . ']', $QoptionsValue->value('sort_order'), 'id="sort_order[' . $i . ']"'); ?></td>
                <td width="10%"><a id="deleteRowBot" class="deleteRowBot"></a></td>
 </tr>
<?php
  $i = $i +1;
  }
?>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addRowBot" value="<?php echo $OSCOM_ProductsAttributesNew->getDef('text_add_row'); ?>" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

My javascript.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = <?php echo $i; ?>

    $("#addRowBot").on("click", function () {
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";

      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[' + counter + ']"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="image[' + counter + ']"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sort_order[' + counter + ']"/></td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDelBot btn btn-md btn-danger" id="deleteRowBot[' + counter + ']" value="<?php echo $button_delete; ?>"></td>';

      newRow.append(cols);
      $("table.order-list-bot").append(newRow);
      counter++;
    });

    $("table.order-list-bot").on("click", ".ibtnDelBot", function (event) {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      counter -= 1
    });
  });
</script>
```

the html

```
<table id="myTableAttributesOptions" class="table table-sm table-hover order-list-option">
            <thead>
              <tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
                <td>text_heading_attributes_option_value_name</td>
                <td>text_heading_attributes_image</td>
                <td>text_heading_attributes_sort_order</td>
                <td class="text-md-right">text_heading_attributes_actions</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><input name="name[0]" value="Small" id="name[0]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td><input name="image[0]" id="image[0]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td class="text-md-right"><input name="sort_order[0]" value="1" id="sort_order[0]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>




                <td width="10%"><a id="deleteRowBot[0]" class="deleteRowBot ibtnDelBot"></a></td>




              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input name="name[1]" value="Medium" id="name[1]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td><input name="image[1]" id="image[1]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td class="text-md-right"><input name="sort_order[1]" value="2" id="sort_order[1]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td width="10%"><a id="deleteRowBot[1]" class="deleteRowBot ibtnDelBot"></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input name="name[2]" value="Large" id="name[2]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td><input name="image[2]" id="image[2]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td class="text-md-right"><input name="sort_order[2]" value="3" id="sort_order[2]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td width="10%"><a id="deleteRowBot[2]" class="deleteRowBot ibtnDelBot"></a></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                  <input class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addRowBot" value="text_add_row" type="button">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

Comment: You have `id="deleteRowBot"` for every php-echo'd row ... `ID` must be unique.

Comment: You have the close `</tr>` on the outside of the while loop as well.

Comment: Side note, `</tfoot` is missing close `>`

Comment: Oups ! Ok thank you, I changed. @IncredibleHat Ok id must be unique I tried this : id="deleteRowBot<?php echo $i; ?>" does'nt work. I have always the row appear when I add a row, but doesn't work for existing row. Tha(s my problem.

Comment: The row you add in your `addRowBot` kinda doesn't match the rows you build using php. You'r issues could be that the PHP version does not have the classes of `ibtnDelBot` added, as well.

Comment: Tk, @IncredibleHat,ok, could you look my html code, I have updated, maybe you can tell me than I can change inside to have this button.